# Is there a way to escape mystery room fights in Disgaea 5?

Tags: disgaea-5

So I've been playing Disgaea 5 for a while, got into the Item World, and after roughly 20 floors I found a mystery room (a bank robbery one). I talked twice to the NPC and I got stuck in a fight with level 3000+ foes. Lost my progress.

Is there a way to escape mystery room fights? Mr. Gency won't work either.

Comment: I should also mention, by avoiding the room, i do mean talking to the slumber cat before you trigger the fight.  Most fights are triggered by talking to the right NPC twice or select an option to fight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one looks like it's either bugged, or intentionally very evil.

The exit portal is there, right under the cat, you just can't see it but it works as normal.

As far as I've seen, there are no actual trap rooms in this one.  You can always escape.

Furthermore, the bank girl is random.  You can safely talk to her between 1 and 4 times before she summons backup, each with more money rewarded.

Comment: If you found that mystery room, there wouldn't be any doubt it's a trap room that you can't escape from.  There is no exit portal after you trigger the fight, and unless you are strong enough, the Guardians will end up killing you.

Comment: There is a portal under the item world guide, just like there is in every other mystery room.  It doesn't display properly, but it is there.  I've escaped from it many times.

Comment: Well it would be good to show some proof, since the closest i can find is a video that selects the slumber cat and the description shows there's a gate under it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JF_V6ZQmLA It's still not confirmed, since there are no videos or screenshots i could find of someone showing you can step on that square and escape (despite it not showing the gate).  I'll upvote your answer, because you are most likely right.

Comment: Confirmed.  I punched the cat off and walked onto that square! Omfg, I thought I was about to lose like an hour of gameplay.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can punch the cat off the exit portal. Triple Strike, or Hurricane Blow both work. It will still be pushed off even if your attack does no damage or even misses.

Comment: In this stage there is no exit portal. I've seen other mystery rooms with one but in the bank one there isn't.

Comment: The exit portal isn't visible on the ground but if you walk on to that tile, it still works.  Thank you so much for posting this.  Real life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Both of the previous answers are half-right, but Omega, the room you are talking about I have come across.  I did the same thing to end up finding myself fighting multiple level 9999 guardians at a low level.

This mystery room you cannot escape from.  It may be 1 of a few (or the only one) that you cannot escape from, because they are trap rooms.  Most rooms you can escape from by killing or knocking off the Slumber Cat from the exit portal and enter it.  The only other option is to finish the room, usually by clearing the room of everything except the slumber cat.

All you can do in the trap rooms is remember what happens in each room and avoid them, or grow strong enough to kill the NPCs next time that happens.  So far the only one I know of is the bank, and is only triggered if you talk to the NPC twice.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to get out the room. They hid the skip portal underneath the cat thing that takes you around the item world!

Even if portal was gone, if you hover over it the description was still there. I got on it like normal and escaped with my 1 million HL. I'm so happy I didn't lose all that damn work too!

Answer (score 0):

You can escape in the bank robbery by pushing the cat away, the warp is invisible, but if you step on the cell you actually get out of the room, just did in , in this exact moment, because i had the same problem, and went looking for solutions XD So escape from that room confirmed, there is no need to make a video.

Answer (score -2):

You can if you realize in bank robbery room the cat is not protected.  Kill him fast if you can if not attack him using range unit  to make him move. When he move send fresh unit from your gate to where he used to stand. And walla 11.110.000 + HL. at least those are the lowest amount from gate key tutorial bank robery room.

P. S.  You cant lift the cat so the only way to move him is fist move or agro him.